# String replace isn't working in for loop - Java

Tags: java, random, char

For some reason this code doesn't work.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Random random = new Random();
            int randomChar = random.nextInt((23 - 0) + 1);
            for(int x = 23;x > 0;x-- ) {

                String text;
                text = original.getText();
                text = text.toLowerCase();
                text = text.replace(alphabet[x], alphabet[randomChar]);

                newText.setText(text);

            }
```

Just to clear a couple things up original and newText are JTextField, and alphabet is a char array with a-z.

Now when I run this it should go through and replace every character with a random one, starting at Z and ending at A however it just gives me the exact same string that I entered back, just converted to lowercase.

It's worth noting that if I replace

```
text = text.replace(alphabet[x], alphabet[randomChar]);
```

With

```
text = text.replace(alphabet[0], alphabet[randomChar]);
```

And put a bunch of A's into the input box it does change them into a random letter. EG:

```
aaaa input
llll output
or gggg output
```

it just doesn't work if I have a variable in there.

The rest of the code isn't important by the way, it's all declaring variables and setting up the GUI.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try printing the random char and entered string within the loop, so that you can debug what is going on and make sure the string actually contains the char.

Comment: Both are working fine, X is decrementing and Random is picking random numbers (Once I moved it inside the for loop, that did not fix the problem btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to moving the random character generation inside the loop (as suggested by @CIsForCoocckies), you'll also need to move the `getText()` and `setText()` calls outside the loop (because each time the loop is run, you start over with the **original** text so at most **one** kind of character would be replaced in the end, no matter how many times the loop iterates.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. I can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

your randomchar is set before the loop with some char and then all chars are replaced to said char so - "yourstring" becomes "xxxxxxxxxx" where x=randomchar

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the two other answers, I'd like to add a comment to the for loop:

```
for(int x = 23;x > 0;x--)
```

You won't enter the loop when x == 0 at all, which means the first char in your alphabet array won't be considered for replacement.

If you have the alphabet array already and want to replace every character with a random one, why not consider using:

```
for (int x = 0; x < alphabet.length; x++){
  //your code here
}
```

This should be better than hard-coding